# How can I get the index of the current element in jQuery each() loop?

Tags: jquery

I have a table, and some of them have input fields on which I need to run validation. After validation I am attaching a class `.mandatory` to the blank input fields. Now later on I need to loop through the `td`s which have `.mandatory` children and get the respective text/html from the respective `th` element of the table.  I thought the best bet is to find the index of the `td` and use that to get the correct `th`, but I don't know how to get the index of the `td` efficiently. I tried something like

```
$('.mandatory').each(function(){
var ind = curr_tr.find('>td').index($(this).closest('td'));//curr_tr is a reference to the current tr I am working with
var txt = $('th:eq('+ind+')').html();
})
```

But this seems inefficient, and won't work if some of the `.mandatory` fields are nested in further tables within the `td`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the parent td for the current input element with `.closest("td")`, and then you can find that td's index (relative to its sibling td elements) with the [`.index()` method](http://api.jquery.com/index/):

```
$('.mandatory').each(function(){
   var ind = $(this).closest('td').index();
   var txt = $('th:eq('+ind+')').html();
});
```

You don't need to a reference to the current tr to do it, and for this purpose you don't pass any parameters to `.index()`.

But allowing for nested tables as per the last sentence in the question, rather than using `.each()` to iterate over all the inputs, you could use it to iterate over the tds that contain mandatory inputs:

```
$('#yourtable > tr > td').has('.mandatory').each(function(){
   // "this" is the td
   var ind = $(this).index();
   var txt = $('#yourtable th:eq('+ind+')').html();
});
```

Where I'm using the [`.has()` method](http://api.jquery.com/has/) to reduce the set of matched td elements to just those with a descendant ".mandatory" element.

(Either way you can't use the index parameter of the `.each()` callback (as shown in other answers) because of course it is an index within all matching elements, not within the current row.)

Answer (score 2):

The index and element is supplied to the callback function.

Use:

```
$('.mandatory').each(function(i){
```

or:

```
$('.mandatory').each(function(i, e){
```

This will give you the index in the `i` parameter, and optionally the element in the `e` parameter. You can natually give the parmeters other names if you like.

Answer (score 1):

`$.each()` has `index` and `element` parameters you can use:

```
$('.mandatory').each(function(index, el){
    var ind = curr_tr.find('>td').index($(this).closest('td')); //curr_tr is a reference to the current tr I am working with
    var txt = $('th:eq('+ind+')').html();
})
```

However, using `index` doesn't sound like the best way to solve your problem. Could you post some HTML so we can see how your DOM is structured. Using a combination of `closest()`, `parent()` etc to traverse it would most likely be a better solution.

Comment: index will give index of '.mandatory' and not it's container 'td', so I don't think that can be used

Answer (score 0):

Just check this for example:

```
 $.each(['first','second'], function(index, value) { 
      alert(index + ': ' + value); 
    });
```